# How do I install Safecracker?

Tags: add-on, safecracker, module, plugin

I've just discovered that Safecracker isn't in the list of modules for the site I'm working on. How do I install it? I'm using EE v2.1.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you upgrade to the current version, 2.5.5, it is bundled within the install.

Comment: Thanks! For anyone else with this problem you can find out how to update EE [here](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/installation/update.html).

Answer (score 0):

You still need to select it as a module to install when installing EE. If you haven't done so then you can install it via Addons > Modules > Safecracker.

Comment: I didn't install it, I took over this from someone else who did before Safecracker was included in EE.

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case what version of EE are you currently running and is it possible for you to upgrade to the latest version?

Comment: It was v2.1.3, now it's updated and the problem is solved.

Comment: That's definitely the easiest way to go about it. :) Glad you got it sorted.